# How to optimize an output (via Genetic Algorithms), given a dataset?

Tags: optimization, genetic-algorithm

I have a .csv file with 5 inputs and 1 ouput. How can I optimize the output via the use of Genetic Algorithms? Many people that have written a tutorial online do not give instructions on problems such as this....They only talk about how to optimize equations.. Any idea of how to proceed? I need to maximize the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is about the same with genetic algorithms. You need to define genes for your problem, have a fitness function and let a lib (or your own) do the optimization process following various parameters (selection, cross overs, mutations rates, etc...).

For your example you can have individuals having 5 genes, for what they need to be i let you decide it depends on the input. If you talk about optimizing the output i guess you already have an idea of how to evaluate it and grade it against other outputs.